# Basic XMLhttprequest retrieving json file data

Tags: javascript, json, xml

I have a basic XML request that gets data from a json file stored on my server. Once the request is loaded a function is called that stores the responseText in a variable called data. Once the data is stored, it is then parsed using JSON.parse and stored into a variable called workouts.

Here is my js code:

```
var data;
var workouts;
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", "workout-db.json");
    req.onload = function() {
        data = req.responseText;
        workouts = JSON.parse(data);
    }
    req.send();
```

Here is my json code:

```
[{
    "name": "Pull up",
    "muscleGroup": "upper",
    "imgUrl": "imgs/pull_up.jpg"
},
{
    "name": "Battle rope",
    "muscleGroup": "upper",
    "imgUrl": "imgs/battle_rope.jpg"
},
{
    "name": "Push up",
    "muscleGroup": "upper",
    "imgUrl": "imgs/push_up.jpg"
}
]
```

Only part I don't understand is how to access this workout object in my code. Trying to call it returns an undefined variable. From what I understand about js scope, the workouts variable should be global and accessible anywhere else in my code.

Comment: This link might be helpful to you, you can go for this useful link - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dOxQkdgllJU&list=PLc7STlqyZm1rd7UI6xV0lNUvVXFmRjxSC&index=11